# List and file operations in python

Tags: python, list, file

I have a file like this: (Dots are some numbers that were used to calculate the average.)

```
Ashe: .....
Azok: .....
Bumba: .....
Thrall: .....
```

And I have list `averages` with one entry for each row (first one is Ashe's; second one; Azok's...)

```
averages = [12.4, 44.8880001, 32.4, 97.701]
```

I split the names with this code:

```
for line in inp:
    line = line.split(": ")[0:1]
```

And when I tried to append each first elements of names and averages (second and second...):

```
for line in inp:
    line = line.split(": ")[0:1]
    #print(line)
    for d in averages:
        line.append(d)
    print(line)
```

I'm having output like this:

```
['Ashe', 12.4, 44.8880001, 32.4, 97.701]
['Azok', 12.4, 44.8880001, 32.4, 97.701]
['Bumba', 12.4, 44.8880001, 32.4, 97.701]
['Thrall', 12.4, 44.8880001, 32.4, 97.701]
```

However, expected output is that:

```
['Ashe', 12.4]
['Azok', 44.8880001]
['Bumba', 32.4]
['Thrall', 97.701]
```

What changes does my code require? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should map each name to each value in `averages` in the order they are placed in the list:

*Assuming total number of names is equal to the length of averages list*:

```
for index, line in enumerate(inp):
    line = line.split(": ")[0:1]
    line.append(averages[index])
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need iterate over each line and each average at the same time. The easiest way to do this is to use `zip()`:

```
for line, avg in zip(inp, averages):
    line = line.split(":")[:1]
    line.append(avg)
    print(line)


['Ashe', 12.4]
['Azok', 44.8880001]
['Bumba', 32.4]
['Thrall', 97.701]
```

For example:

```
for value1, value2 in zip('abc', 'xyz'):
    print(value1, value2)

a x
b y
c z
```

Here the strings `abc` and `xyz` are zipped together, so that one element of each is used at a time.

In addition, tuple unpacking happens. Looping through the zipped strings actually gives you tuples:

```
for x in zip('abc', 'xyz'):
    print(x)

('a', 'x')
('b', 'y')
('c', 'z')
```

But in the first iteration, `a` and `x` are assigned `value1`, and `value2`:

```
>>> value1, value2 = ('a', 'x')
>>> value1
'a'
>>> value2
'x'
```

In the second:

```
>>> value1, value2 = ('b', 'y')
>>> value1
'b'
>>> value2
'y'
```